# C# application with Visual programming editor

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am looking for a user interface component that will allow my users to visually edit the parameters of a simulation project. I am not looking for something elaborate but a user interface similar to the one that is available in Visual Studio Domain Specific Languages. Essentially I want to provide a toolbox with a few components and then an editor where users can drag and drop the components and connect them. Anything you have come across?

I am using Visual Studio 2010, C#, the DevExpress user interface components for the front-end and it's all winforms.

Comment: What UI framework will you be using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and C#. Sorry for not having the screenshot yet but there seems to be a problem.

Comment: You can look into extending/customizing the Visual Studio Shell.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682179/visual-studio-shell-creating-a-custom-ide

Comment: So, you want to write a Visual Studio plugin?

Comment: Hmmm that's the problem I don't want to write a Visual Studio Shell or plugin because I have my front-end in devexpress. I want to build something really simple.

Comment: WPF? Windows Forms? Silverlight? ASP.NET WebForms? ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio isolated shell might be a good start!

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee524005.aspx

You can even design your own [debug engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb161718%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to compile and build code for your specific languages such as Python, Lisp etc.

Answer (score 1):

The closes thing that springs to mind is the design experience for [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328)? Perhaps XAML is the way forward..